# Como chamar um Html.Action("minha_página") via jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma página que carrega várias partials views, quero chamar em um modal uma página em específico que irá preencher toda a tela.
Estou usando uma comando jquery genérico para chamar uma action que será passada por parâmetros.

Esse é o botão

```
<button type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in loopa" data-id="_ArquivosProcDia"></button>
```

Esse é a div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="abrezoompagina">
                @Html.Action("_ArquivosProcDia")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o script

```
<script>
$(".loopa").click(function () {
    var part = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var part2 = $(this).replaceWith(@(Html.Action(part));
    $("#modal4").modal();
});
```

Cada partial view terá sua própria lupa para trazer o modal com suas informações, a partial que será aberta nesse exemplo será o **_ArquivosProcDia**.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem qual é a sua dúvida. Poderia explicar um pouco mais?

Comment: Sim claro, bom eu gostaria de criar um script genérico para chamar várias partials que estão na index principal. Eu carrego a partial via razor, mas o camando @Html.Action("partial_view") não pode ser inserido no jquery pois ele carrega o conteúdo lá. Eu quero ver se é possível chamar essas partial de forma a usar apenas um script, passando os parâmetros da partial pelo data-id do botão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que faz o seu código, mas nos meus sistemas eu costumo enxertar a modal no HTML assim:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#meu-botao").click(function () {
                $.get(@Url.Action("_ArquivosProcDia"), function (template) {
                    $("#alguma-div").append(template);
                    // Aqui coloco um código pra chamar a Modal.
                });
            });
        </script>
```

De qualquer forma, seu código não vai funcionar. Para funcionar, teria que ser algo assim:

```
$(".loopa").click(function () {
    var part = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var part2 = $(this).replaceWith(@Url.Action(part));
    $("#modal4").modal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tive que fazer assim pra funcionar, mas vou ter que repetir para cada modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".loopa").click(function () {
    var part = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.get("@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("_ArquivosProcDia", "Home")))", function (template) {
        $("#abrezoompagina").replaceWith(template);
        $("#modal4").modal();
    });
});
```